# What is "meta_input" parameter in wp_insert_post() used for?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, wp-insert-post

I am inserting some post into wordpress using the function [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/).

I want to insert some custom fields on each post and reading the documentation I though the meta_info parameter was used for that, I tried something like this:

```
$data = array(
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_title' => $post->getTitle(),
        'post_content' => $post->getContent(),
        'post_category' => $post->getCategory(),
        'tags_input' => $post->getTags(),
        'meta_input' => array( "_test" => "testx1" )
);

$postID = wp_insert_post( $data );
```

The post gets inserted correctly and tags too. But there are no custom fields added. I know I could use *add_post_meta()* to add them but I still would like to know what the *meta_input* parameter is used for, because I did a search on the database for "testx1" after inserting the post and couldn't find any result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This part of [`wp_insert_posts()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3259) gives it away:

```
  if ( ! empty( $postarr['meta_input'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $postarr['meta_input'] as $field => $value ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, $field, $value );
        }
  }
```

where we see how the post meta fields are updated/added with `update_post_meta()`.

Here's the inline description for `meta_input`:

> Array of post meta values keyed by their post meta key. Default empty.

This was added in WordPress 4.4 and here's relevant ticket [#20451](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20451) for more information.

Note that using the underscore in front of the  the meta key `_test` will hide it from the *custom fields* metabox in the post edit screen.

Comment: Ohh, the wp im testing on is 4.3, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is via term_id not slug and it works:

```
//insert Art items into database
$arr = array('item 1', 'item 2');
// $arr = array('art item 1', 'art item 2');

foreach ($arr as $a) { 
    wp_insert_post(array(
    //essentials
    //'ID'      => 1131,
    'post_author'       => 1,
    'post_title'        => $a,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_content'      => 'Something...',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'post_name'         => 'post name',
    'meta_input'        => array( //(array) Array of post meta values keyed by their post meta key. Default empty.
        'city'     => '',// 'name' => $post['name']
        'country'  => ''// 'city' => $post['city']
    ),
    'tax_input'    => array(
        'category' => array(33,32), //id numbers work, slugs tend to be ignored !!!
        'post_tag' => array('one', 'two') //for tags slugs seem to work
    ),//(array) Array of taxonomy terms keyed by their taxonomy name. Default empty. Equivalent to calling wp_set_post_terms() / wp_set_object_terms()
    //'tags_input'  => array('una', 'trei'), //(array) Array of tag names, slugs, or IDs. Default empty. Equivalent to calling wp_set_post_tags().
    ), true);   
}
```