# wp_insert_post add meta_input

Tags: wp-insert-post, input

In the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) of `wp_insert_post` there is a changelog on half of the page which says the following:

> Since: WordPress 4.4.0 A 'meta_input' array can now be passed to
>   $postarr to add post meta data.

I'm using Wordpress 4.4.2. I'll try to add a new post by running the code as follows:

```
function handle_post($post) 
{
    wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_title'    => $post['title'],
        'post_type'     => 'werknemers',
        'meta_input'    => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'name',
                'value' => $post['name']
            ),
            array(
                'key'   => 'city',
                'value' => $post['city']
            )
        )
    ) ); 
}
```

The post is added to the database, but without meta data. 
I've found [this stack post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216178/what-is-meta-input-parameter-in-wp-insert-post-used-for), but I can't figure out how to implement the `if statement`.

I'm also interested in the way to add taxonomies (tax_input).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`meta_input` is just a single-dimension array as `key => value`:

```
'meta_input' => array(
    'name' => $post['name'],
    'city' => $post['city']
)
```

`tax_input` is slightly different, with tax as key and an array of values:

```
'tax_input' => array( 
    'taxonomy_name' => array( 
        'term', 
        'term2', 
        'term3' 
    ) 
)
```

Note that for `tax_input` to work, the user currently logged in when the code runs has to have the capability to manage that taxonomy, otherwise it will fail silently.

Comment: Sorry for the late respons, but thanks for the clear explanation! Totally worked out as expected